# Redirect in .htaccess based on ID (lower / greater) present in the URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling with a redirect that at the beginning seamed to me as simple but it is not. I want to do a redirect in .htaccess file based on the numerical ID present in the input URL.
Ex. https://example.com/bla-id200000.html

- If 'id' > 200000 redirect to https://example.com/item?id=300000
- If 'id' < 200000 redirect to https://subdomain.example.com/item?id=100000

ID can have either 6 or 7 digits

my first try was to ask chatgpt, it gave me few clues but in the end wasted circa 2 hours of my time, as it's solution didn't work. According to chatgpt the problem is RewriteCond does not support direct comparison operators like < for capturing group matches.

Can anyone give me a hand with this? Any hint will be appreciated :)

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)-id(\d+)\.html$
RewriteCond %2<200000
RewriteRule .* https://subdomain.example.com/item?id=%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)-id(\d+)\.html$
RewriteRule .* item?id=%2 [L,QSA]
```

the result was: Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

If you have Apache 2.4+ you can use [`expr`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html) with numerical operators, which are:

- -eq  equals
- -ne  not equals
- -lt  lower than
- -le  lower or equal
- -gt  greater than
- -ge  greater or equal

So you can try this instead of `RewriteCond %2<200000`:

```
RewriteCond expr "%2 -lt 200000"
```

There is also an integer comparison `integercomp` but I find no example of its use, probably something like `RewriteCond integercomp %2 -lt 200000`

Comment: Thank you, however it doesn't work. It looks like %2 argument is not getting passed to RewriteCond expr "%2 -lt 200000" or is not allowed in expr

Comment: when i input RewriteCond expr "999999 -lt 200000" this rule works fine. I just cannot access the %2 variable

Comment: Hmm, have you tried to test if you actually capture the good values, for example in a test redirection `RewriteRule .* item?id=%2&test=%1 [L,QSA]` and checking in the script what you get? it may be your regex or the syntax, sometimes, I don't know why, expressions that don't work raw can work when inside double quotes ""

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it!

```
RewriteCond   "%1" "<200000"
```

The above works just fine.

Comment: Be careful that you should still use `-lt` because even if `<` seems to work, the comparison is lexicographic (eg alphabetic, haven't tested in .htaccess but in theory `"320" < "2000"` will be false because `"3" > "2"`)

Comment: tested and luckily it works as it should